# сделать бэкграунды кликабельными

Tags: html, css

Есть слайдер из фоновых изображений:

HTML разметка:

```
<ul class="body_slides">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS стили:

```
.body_slides {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:-2; 
    background:#000;}
.body_slides,
.body_slides:after{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;} 
.body_slides:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(images/pattern.png) repeat top left;}


.body_slides li{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:none;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation: anim_slides 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: anim_slides 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: anim_slides 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: anim_slides 18s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: anim_slides 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.body_slides li:nth-child(1){
background-image: url(images/1.jpg) 
}
.body_slides li:nth-child(2){
-webkit-animation-delay: 6.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 6.0s;
background-image: url(images/2.jpg)  
} 
.body_slides li:nth-child(3){
-webkit-animation-delay: 12.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 12.0s;
background-image: url(images/3.jpg) 
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
0% {opacity:0;}
6% {opacity:1;}
24% {opacity:1;}
30% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slides {
0% {opacity:0;}
6% {opacity:1;}
24% {opacity:1;}
30% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы каждый из бэкграундов был кликабелен и каждый со своей ссылкой? 
Спасибо.

Comment: разметку можете изменить ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="body_slides" onClick='location.href=link'>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если html-разметку менять можно, то

```
<style>
    .body_slides a { display: block; }
</style>

<li><a href=''></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если можно менять разметку, что было бы правильнее – вставьте ссылку в каждый li, в href указав адрес. Для ссылки по всей площади:

```
.body_slides li a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Если не можете – думаю придется писать на js что-то вроде обработчика. Например получение номера слайда и на основе этого в switch осуществлять редирект по нужной ссылке.